# VB.NET My.Settings Datatable is not saving

Tags: vb.net, datatable, my.settings

i have a datatable that i want to save to a My.Settings Datatable However when i reopen the application i find that the table is not saved

```
My.Settings.Datatable = someDatatable
```

is there something wrong with the above statement or something else that i should do?

Comment: did you call My.Settings.Save()?

Comment: yes and also tried Naming the table and same problem

Comment: i already did it with XML and its working fine, also i tried saving it to an XML Document stored in My.Settings and same problem!

Comment: I found the naming of the dataTable crucial. Got an error without tablename, no error with tablename!!

Comment: just add columns manually and it will work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign a [`TableName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename.aspx), for example:

```
If My.Settings.Datatable Is Nothing Then
    My.Settings.Datatable = New DataTable
    My.Settings.Datatable.TableName = "Datatable"
    My.Settings.Datatable.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 1000
        My.Settings.Datatable.Rows.Add(i)
    Next
    My.Settings.Save()
End If
```

If i reopen the application the datatable still exists.

Comment: This works bit when i do it with my table which have huge number of records and columns it doesnt work..i will try to Add the columns first, i'll post back :)

Comment: as expected it was about that i had to Add all coulmns! and really thank you very much